# Displaying array data in blade view - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have successfully fetched two items from an API but when displaying on my view, only one item is showing on my view. What could i be doing wrong in my code below ?

When i echo `results`, i am able to see that two items are being returned although just one is displayed on the view.

PS: Beginner in Laravel & PHP

**Controller**

```
    public function fetch()
    {
            $response = $client->request('/users/99979100/videos', array(), 'GET');
            $results =  json_decode(json_encode($response),true);
            $export_details = $results;
            return view('home',compact('export_details'));
}
```

**View**

```
  <div class="video-title">
  <a href="#">{{$export_details['body']['data'][0]['name']}} - {{$export_details['body']['data'][0]['description']}} </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you expect? You're only echoing one row. Try using a loop on `$export_details`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through your results...

```
@foreach($export_details['body']['data'] as $export_detail)
    <a href="#">{{$export_detail['name']}} - {{$export_detail['description']}} </a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your array which you are returning to your view,
I am not sure what exactly your array contains but you should be able to do something like this in your blade file:

```
@foreach($export_details as $exportKey => $exportValue)
    <p>{{ $exportValue }}</p>
@endforeach
```

If you array contains multiple array you need to create multiple loop in your foreach. Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops) for more information.